# Spring boot REST gets params to HTTPConnectionURL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have spring boot application in which I get the streamName as a parameter, but now I don't want it to work in postman, but in another program in which the streamName is String that is created when calling a function. Previously I was giving it as json, but now I want to give it as parameter and I have no idea how can I do it.

This is my Request in Spring boot:

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseBody
public String addStream(@RequestParam("streamName") String streamName) {

    String key = getRandomHexString();
    streamService.addStream(new Stream(streamName,key));
    return key;
}
```

and this is in another program where i want to make this method:

```
public void onHTTPPostRequest(String streamName) throws IOException {

    PostResponse postResponse = new PostResponse();
    postResponse.setStreamName(streamName);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(postResponse);

    getLogger().info("POST Body  " + jsonString);

    URL pipedreamURL = new URL("http://10.100.2.44:8080/api?streamName=");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) pipedreamURL.openConnection();

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    os.write(jsonString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    os.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    getLogger().info(responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add it to the URL string:

```
URL pipedreamURL = new URL("http://10.100.2.44:8080/api?streamName=" + streamName);
```